# SQLite Query - A short list of individual records which appear multiple times and ordered by the number of times they occur?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Say I have a table with the following records:

| ID | Type | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | food | apple |
| 2 | food | apple |
| 3 | food | orange |
| 4 | food | apple |
| 5 | food | banana |
| 6 | food | banana |
| 7 | drink | cola |
| 8 | drink | water |
| 9 | food | banana |
| 10 | food | apple |

How do I construct a query that will return a single column list of Items, which are only of the Type:food, and which just contains one occurrence of each item which appears multiple times in the table - and finally are ordered by the number of times they appear in the table?

So the result for the above table would be the following list:

1. apple (4 occurrences)
2. banana (3 occurrences)
3. orange (1 occurrence)

Thanks.

Comment: Use `count` and `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Item, count(Item) as COUNT
FROM TableName
WHERE Type='food'
GROUP BY Item
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

Result:

```
ITEM    COUNT
apple   4
banana  3
orange  1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/030ee/6).

Answer (score 2):

**This query will do it !**

```
 select count(*) as Total ,item from tbl 
   where type='food'
    group by item order by Total desc;
```

**Also check the fiddle demo:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3c6/3

Comment: Ah, actually it almost works, but also returns the cola and water records which I don't want as they are Type=drink not Type=food...I see from answer below I need to add the WHERE Type='food' line.